# EntityFrameworkCore.SQLLite and UWP Not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I am just starting to get in to UWP.  I am writing an app that uses code first to create databases.  I am following the tutorial at http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/gettimg-started.

So i have created my data model and also created the console app that is used to trigger the migrations.  I have installed the tools into the console app and set a reference to my data model.  This is the data model code :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

using MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Objects;

namespace MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Model
{
    public class DataModel : DbContext
    {

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=BookByMagic.db");
    }

    public DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmailType> EmailTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonType> PersonTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneType> PhoneTypes { get; set; }

}
```

}

Now to kick off all the migration goodness the tutorial says to run "Add-Migration InitialCreate -StartupProject

When i run this i get :

No DbContext was found in assembly 'MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Migrations'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

After 3 hours of searching goole i have failed to find anything that explains the reason this error would occur.

Im using visual studio 2007 15.9.4

Any help greatly appreciated as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have got to the bottom of it.  There is an error in the tutorial.

So the command they tell you to type is

Add-Migration InitialCreate -StartupProject MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Migrations

What you have to type is

Add-Migration InitialCreate -Project MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Model -StartupProject MWSoft.BookByMagic.Data.Migrations

I hope this helps someone in the future.